# How to start with powerbi and nodejs

Tags: node.js, powerbi

I am trying to log into MS PowerBI services, but I don't know how to.
I have my app setted up in MS pwrBI portal with a valid user, it returned me a client id and a client secret.
But I'm stucked in how do I start to use pwrBi dashboards in my node aoo. I looking for "nodeJs+PowerBI" for dummies (being the dummy myself)

Thanks

Comment: You use Power BI Service or PowerBI Embedded?

Comment: I'm starting right from zero, don't know which one to use, but as far as I could see I think I'll use embedded pwrBI.

Comment: You can follow this https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Node

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've tryed it but it gives: { [Error: connect ETIMEDOUT 13.69.244.213:443]
  code: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  errno: 'ETIMEDOUT',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '13.69.244.213',
  port: 443 }

Comment: BTW I'm behind a corporate proxy which, I have no idea, if it blocks 443 port or not.

Comment: Sorry I have no idea on this stuff